# Emacs not recognising .emacs.d folder on startup

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, dot-emacs

I'm new to Emacs. I recently got a dot-emacs configuration from GitHub. Cloned the repo in my home directory as .emacs.d

This is for setting up a clojure environment. When i open Emacs and enter 
M-x nrepl-jack-in, the minibuf displays 'No Match'

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: Whose config did you clone?  That's kinda important.

Comment: It was in his previous question: https://github.com/ghoseb/dotemacs - it looks like a rough reworking of Emacs Live.

Comment: Yup, that's the one. You're one of the most helpful folks on this site. :) Thanks.

Comment: What type of system are you on?  Emacs is going to look for `.emacs.d` in your HOME folder, which may not be where you think if you're on Windows.

Comment: I'm using OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: What does Emacs report when you type `C-h v user-init-file RET` ?

Comment: phils has the best solution here. I was having this same problem, unable to get spacemacs to start, and it turns out that the version I downloaded was precompiled to initialize from ~/.config/emacs/init.el rather than the standard ~/.emacs.d/init.el. Typing `C-h v user-init-file RET` showed me where it was looking, and I copied the spacemacs files into there and bingo.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that nREPL isn't being loaded. Add the following to your `init.el`:

```
(autoload 'nrepl-jack-in "nrepl" nil t)
```

You should be able to run it now with `M-x nrepl-jack-in`.

---

If the command doesn't work you'll need to do some troubleshooting.

- make sure that nREPL is actually installed. You'll need both the [Emacs library](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el) and the [nREPL server](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl).
- check for any errors during startup. Launch Emacs from the terminal using the `--d` flag:

  `emacs --d`

  You will get a backtrace if anything goes wrong during the startup.
- verify that your init.el is actually being loaded. Add the following code to the end of your init.el and restart Emacs.

  `(message "---> LOADED")`

  This will show in your `*Messages*` buffer if everything is being loaded.

---

### Edit:

Looks like your init.el isn't being loaded. Check your home folder for files called `.emacs` or `.emacs.el`, which might be getting loaded instead.

Otherwise it could still be a path issue. Open a terminal and make sure this is the file you expect:

```
less ~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

Comment: I tried emacs --d, there are no errors during startup. It loads Emacs perfectly. I'm not getting the LOADED message in the Messages buffer.What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: That means it's not loading your init.el.